# jqgrid: how to send search operator information to server side

Tags: jqgrid

I have setup grid instance something like this:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'rest/usertest/users', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ["Username", "Name", "Grouping"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "username" },
            { name: "name", width: 90 },
            { name: "grouping", width: 80, sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "username",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true, 
        multiselect: false, 
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto', 
        gridview: true,
        multiSort: true
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter : false,searchOperators : true});
```

I am trying to do a server side operand based search via grid. The problem is that it doesn't send any information about the chosen operator to the server-side. **The request does not contain any information about the selected operator (eq, bw, bn etc).**

I am trying to do so with the toolbar search itself. Am I missing any configuration parameter? Please advice.

---

EDIT:

I tried the answer given below by @Tomcat, however it still does not work. The search is successful but I am not able to the make the operand based search work on server side.

As in the pic below, there is not info about the chosen operand.

[image: request]

Answer (score 2):

Having `stringResult : true` is necessary.

```
    $('#list').filterToolbar({
        groupOp: 'OR',
        defaultSearch: "cn",
        autosearch: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        searchOperators: true, // activates the operators menu
        stringResult : true // activates multi-field search
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the grid setup next properties:

```
searchOperators: true,
search: true,
```

After that request to the server should contain the next parameters:
"filters" - search filter,
"sidx" -filed for sorting,
"sord" - sorting order ('asc' or 'desc'), '_search' - bool trigger for searching.

---

Ok, please take a look at this code, it works and send all the necessary information. Pay attention to the **jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {** properties.

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        searchOnEnter: false,
        searchOperators: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        stringResult: true,
        groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR", text: "any" }],
        defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true
    });
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Nope, still does not work. I am have edited the question. Please take a look.